# Scheduling a query with custom times

Tags: google-bigquery

I am trying to schedule a query in BigQuery so that it runs each day, **every 30 minutes** running **between the hours of 7:00 am and 11:30 am**.

I believed the following should work in the custom schedule field:

> every 30 minutes between 7:00 and 11:30

When I try this, the following error is displayed:

> Error creating scheduled query: The specified schedule is invalid: [every 30 minutes between 7:00 and 11:30]

I can schedule it to run every 30 minutes with no issue, but this will run the query many more times each day than is necessary.

Comment: What scheduler are you using?

Comment: I have added a general answer regarding custom scheduling in BigQuery here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884566/bigquery-custom-schedule-cron-syntax-not-accepted/64770481#64770481

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are having an error because you are using `between - and` instead of `from - to`.

I have found and [example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries#setting_up_a_manual_run_on_historical_dates):

> every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00

So, I tried with: `every 30 minutes from 07:00 to 11:30`, and worked as expected.

Comment: For a more general answer, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56884566/bigquery-custom-schedule-cron-syntax-not-accepted/64770481#64770481