# Bigquery Custom Schedule Cron Syntax Not Accepted

Tags: cron, google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

I am trying to schedule a query to run intraday in Bigquery UI. According to Google's documentation this option uses cron syntax. I have used crontab guru to verify the syntax is correct, although it doesn't matter what syntax you put the scheduler doesn't seem to accept any. Is this a known bug? Below is the cron syntax I'm using to run every 6 hours.

0 */6 * * *

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This post attempts to give a more general answer for those that may follow with similar questions.

A full description of the allowed syntax can be found directly [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/python/scheduling-jobs-with-cron-yaml?hl=en_GB#the_schedule_format) as well as related materials [here under "schedule" field information](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery-transfer/docs/reference/datatransfer/rest/v1/projects.locations.transferConfigs?hl=en_GB)..

For full disclosure, I'm going to lift out some parts directly from that documentation here so this answer can "stand alone".

Generally, the schedule must be of the form:

[TYPE] [INTERVAL_VALUE] [INTERVAL_SCOPE]

and you must decide which of the three different kinds of intervals you will use:

- End-time intervals
- Start-time intervals
- Custom intervals

The kind of interval is chosen implicitly by the schedule you provide.

## End-Time Intervals

These are intervals implemented from when a job finishes.

**TYPE**

Daily intervals must start with the "`every`" prefix

**INTERVAL_VALUE**

Valid units of time are as follows:

- `minutes` or `mins`
- `hours`

**INTERVAL_SCOPE**

Not applicable for end-time intervals.

**Example**

If "`every 5 mins`", and the job finishes at 0201, then then next job waits 5 minutes AFTER completion to begin again, and starts at 0206.

## Start-Time Intervals

A strict schedule for the queries to follow.

**TYPE**

Daily intervals must start with the "`every`" prefix

**INTERVAL_VALUE**

Some integer amount of the following units of time:

- `minutes` or `mins`
- `hours`

The units remain the same even using 1 as the amount.

**INTERVAL_SCOPE**

Must be of the form:

`from [HH:MM] to [HH:MM]` with HH=00,01,...,23 and MM=00,01,..., 59.
OR
`synchronized`

`synchronized` repeats a time interval and spreads it evenly across the 24 hour period (e.g. like end-time scheduling but fixing it to a start-time).

The [INTERVAL_VALUE] given in conjunction with this option must be a factor of 24 (1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 8, 12, or 24), presumably so that each day has the same schedule (otherwise, you would get a "spill" over into the next day).

**Examples**

Example 1: `every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00`
If the job starts at 1000, and takes 6 minutes, then it will run 1000, 1010, 1020, ..., because the 1005,1015, ..., jobs were skipped because they were still running.

Direct quote:

> Because the start time of a job is strict, if an instance of a job
> runs longer than the defined time interval, **then the Cron service can
> skip a job**. An individual start time in the interval can be skipped if
> the prior job has not completed or times out.

*Example 2:* `every 2 hours synchronized`
Runs 0000,0200,0400, ..., 2200.

## Custom Intervals

These specify intervals on the day or month level, and cannot specify sub-daily intervals.

**TYPE**

- Using `every` specifies a repeating interval:

  - `every day 06:00`
  - `every monday`
  - `every tuesday`
  - ...
  - `every sunday`
- Specific days can be specified with ordinal numbers (`1st`, `2nd`, `3rd`, OR, `first`, `second`, `third`, ..., up to `31st` OR `thirtyfirst`)

  - `1st,3rd tuesday`
  - `2nd, third wednesday of month 09:00`

Note that the ordinal number and words can be mixed.

**INTERVAL_VALUE**
Valid days are any mix of the following:

- `monday` or `mon`
- `tuesday` or `tue`
- `wednesday` or `wed`
- `thursday` or `thu`
- `friday` or `fri`
- `saturday` or `sat`
- `sunday` or `sun`
- `day` for all days of the week

**INTERVAL_SCOPE**
Can include

- `of month [HH:MM]`
- `of jan,feb,sep,nov [HH:MM]`   i.e. a comma-separated list of months

Note, a time must be given with any given month, with `HH` and `MM` given as above (00-23 and 00-59, respectively). If "of" is excluded, the job runs every month.

Allowed values:

- `january` or `jan`
- `february` or `feb`
- `march` or `mar`
- `april` or `apr`
- `may`
- `june` or `jun`
- `july` or `jul`
- `august` or `aug`
- `september` or `sep`
- `october` or `oct`
- `november` or `nov`
- `december` or `dec`
- `month` for all months in the year

**Examples**

- `2nd monday,thu`
- `1,8,15,22 of month 09:00`
- `1st mon,wednesday,thu of sep,oct,nov 17:00`

Note, there is no documentation that could be found describing the time a job runs when the time is not explicitly specified (e.g. `2nd monday,thu`).

## General Examples

- `second monday,thu` -> "Custom Interval"
- `third, twentysecond, 30th mon` -> "Custom Interval"
- `1 of jan,april,july,oct 00:00`  -> "Custom Interval"
- `1st monday of sep,oct,nov 09:00` -> "Custom Interval"
- `1st,third monday of month 04:00`  -> "Custom Interval"
- `1,8,15,22 of month 09:00`   -> "Custom Interval"
- `every monday 09:00`  -> "Custom Interval"
- `every 5 minutes from 10:00 to 14:00` -> "Start-time Interval"
- `every 1 hours from 08:00 to 16:00` -> "Start-time Interval"
- `every 2 hours synchronized` -> "Start-time Interval"
- `every 5 minutes` -> "End-time Interval"
- `every 1 hours` -> "End-time Interval"

**IMPORTANT:**

- Interval types are chosen implicitly when you enter the schedule
- You can't mix and match the options for the different interval types.
- All specified times are UTC

As said in the intro above, this information is essentially ripped from the existing documentation, but I felt that was buried away and that this question deserved a "stand alone" reference text.

Answer (score 5):

Form the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries?hl=en_GB&_ga=2.149262838.-113875156.1553685966):

> When selecting Custom, a Cron-like time specification is expected, for
>   example every 3 hours. The shortest allowed period is fifteen minutes.
>   See the schedule field under TransferConfig for additional valid API
>   values.

The expected format is "Cron-like" but not pure Cron. Replace your Cron syntax with `every 6 hours` and this will work (note that this is UTC time), see example below:

[image]

Comment: Additionally, when you hover the mouse on the "?" symbol next to the custom schedule legend, some examples are provided: 
"The specified times are in UTC. Examples of valid format:
'1st,3rd monday of month 15:30'
'every wed,fri of jan,jun 13:15'
'first sunday of quarter 00:00'
'every 4 hours' "

Comment: Has anyone found a way to schedule this at two specific times each day? I'm trying for something like "daily at 12:00, 13:00" and it does not like my syntax